# A django model that subclasses an abc, gives a metaclass conflict

Tags: python, django, conflict, metaclass, abc

I have a following model and abstract base class

```
import abc
from django.db import models


class AbstractBase():
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def my_method(self):
        return


class MyModel(models.Model, AbstractBase):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def my_method(self):
        return 1
```

But I am getting the following error.

> metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a
>   (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

I think the problem here is (As it is described here http://code.activestate.com/recipes/204197-solving-the-metaclass-conflict/) that two base class has two different metaclasses so python cannot decide which metaclass to use for child object.

In order to solve this I removed multiple inheritence and use following register method to register child class

```
abc.register(Child)
```

But I did not really like this approach since it looks like monkey patching.

Is there another way to solve this problem?

I try to assign Model metaclass to Child explicitly but it did not work.
I am not looking for a way to solve it by writing code. I think this must be solved by changing my class structure.

Comment: I think you're going to have to create a new metaclass that does both django's and abc's things, probably by calling their respective metaclasses in order, maybe using inheritance.

Comment: There is nothing hackish about using the abs.register method - it is designed exactly for these cases. BTW, Python way o f thinking things is done  so you rarely should _need_ interfaces and such - maybe you are too constrained by the way things are done in static languages?

Comment: @jsbueno - You might be right, but I will need to implement interface functionality in some way. Here is an example implantation- https://gist.github.com/1559689 . Is there a better way to implement this functionality, in python?

Answer (score 2):

Apart from creating a new metaclass that inherits from both `ABCMeta` and `ModelBase`, <del>or making `ABCMeta` inherit from `ModelBase`,</del> there isn't much you can do.

However, possibly a different registration pattern might be appropriate? <del>Maybe something like `contrib.admin.autodiscover`?</del> Or a class decorator? Or a loop at the bottom of the `.py` file which calls `register` on the appropriate classes (ex, `for var in globals().values(): if isinstance(var, type) and issubclass(var, AbastractBase): register(var)`)?

**Edit**: D'oh. I'd assumed that `ABCMeta` was an example, not [`ABCMeta`](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta). That's what I get for browsing StackOverflow on too little sleep.

Comment: My conclusion about this is If I am using abc's as an interface, I should use abc.register. I really think that there should be a better way to implement an interface(http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0245/). Without them oo features of python seems very weak to me.

Comment: If you feel that this "makes Python's OO weak", then I might humbly suggest that your understanding of the "requirements for strong OO" differ drastically from those of Python's designers (or that you accidentally typed "oo" when you meant to type "static type checking"?)